# How can I log when the postfix (for an incoming mail server) enters the stressed condition?

Tags: postfix, bash, stress-testing

I have a server that I use only for incoming emails it uses Postfix as MTA. I want the postfix logs to indicate when (and if) the MTA enters the stressed mode. I thought about writing a custom bash script for it (by checking for stress=yes) in the process list, but I guess this logic is not correct as if the server is stressed there's a high probability that the server may be low on resources too so in this condition checking using script should be avoided. How can I address this issue or handle this problem?

Comment: If you are concerned that your logging infrastructure might consume too much resources, maybe there is a flaw two steps earlier - in your capacity planning. Recording tens of thousands of metrics multiple times a second should not be a resource consumption problem, not on a machine that needs to not fail serving legitimate clients while also being busy with a number of spam bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the postfix logs to indicate when (and if) the MTA enters the
> stressed mode.

**That is the default.** The trigger for enabling the stress mechanism is reaching the configured limit for a service - and every time that happens, you will find in your logs:

```
warning: service "foo" (bar) has reached its process limit "123": new clients may experience noticeable delays
```

> the MTA enters the stressed mode

Clarification, because it bit me in the past: this is not an MTA-wide mechanism - it works per-service. You may think of it just the same on systems serving clients via a single service  (port 25) - until you open up a separate service on a different IP or port (e.g. authenticated submission). Then one may be operating under stress=yes regime, while another is not.

Comment: Thanks, I stupidly missed that part in the documentation.